# Get the SurfaceListBoxItem and ScatterViewItem when object is dropped on a SurfaceListBox and ScatterView

Tags: c#, xaml, pixelsense

I'm dropping an object (`ScatterViewItem`) on a `SurfaceListBox` with the `s:SurfaceDragDrop` event, and it works fine when detecting the dropping on the whole `SurfaceListBox`, however, I want to know in which `SurfaceListBoxItem` the object was dropped.

I also want to do this but for a `ScatterView`, i.e., detecting which `ScatterViewItem` of that `ScatterView` the object was dropped on.

My code is something like this:

```
<s:SurfaceListBox 
    x:Name="listBoxList"
    Background="{x:Null}"
    AllowDrop="True"
    s:SurfaceDragDrop.Drop="ListBox_Drop" >
</s:SurfaceListBox>

<s:ScatterView 
    x:Name="scatterList"
    Background="{x:Null}"
    AllowDrop="True"
    s:SurfaceDragDrop.Drop="Scatter_Drop" >
</s:ScatterView>
```

And then I add my items:

```
listBoxList.Items.Add("ListBox Item 1");
listBoxList.Items.Add("ListBox Item 1");
listBoxList.Items.Add("ListBox Item 1");

scatterList.Items.Add("ScatterViewItem A");
scatterList.Items.Add("ScatterViewItem B");
scatterList.Items.Add("ScatterViewItem C");
```

So how can I get the item on the `ListBox_Drop` and `Scatter_Drop`?

**EDIT**

Through Robert answer I managed to solve my problem. So the resulting code would be something like this (for the `ScatterView`):

```
<s:ScatterView
    x:Name="scatterList"
    Background="{x:Null}">
    <s:ScatterView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="s:ScatterViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="s:SurfaceDragDrop.Drop" Handler="Scatter_Drop"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </s:ScatterView.ItemContainerStyle>
</s:ScatterView>
```

And for the `SurfaceListBox`:

```
<s:SurfaceListBox
    x:Name="listBoxList"
    Background="{x:Null}">
    <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="s:SurfaceListBox">
            <EventSetter Event="s:SurfaceDragDrop.Drop" Handler="ListBox_Drop"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</s:SurfaceListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `AllowDrop` and hook up your Drop event handler for each individual `ScatterViewItem` & `ListBoxItem`.  Then the source of the event will be the item that got dropped upon.

Comment: That does work, but it doesn't seem the proper way to do it. If I have 50 items I should have one drop event and not 50. Enlighten me if I'm missing something here.

Comment: you can have all 50 items point to the exact same event handler function, but each item needs to have AllowDrop set on it directly

Comment: Thank you Robert for the info, I solved it and the solution is in my first post.

Answer (score 1):

A small correction I think to the above solution.

```
<Style TargetType="s:SurfaceListBoxItem">
```

as oppose to

```
<Style TargetType="s:SurfaceListBox">
```